# Spring Integration JMS/IBM MQ: how to send different message to different queue in parallel

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am working with a project which is using JMS listener to receive incoming message, and then route to different destination, currently the process only pick one destination among below 3 for each incoming message. so the xml configuration is written as below

```
<integration:router ref="jmsRouter" input-channel="jmsFilterOutput" default-output-channel="jmsRouterOutput"  />

<integration:service-activator id="serviceActivator1" input-channel="input1"
                               ref="messageProcessService" method="callMsgProcessor1" />
                               
<integration:service-activator id="serviceActivator2" input-channel="input2"
                               ref="messageProcessService" method="callMsgProcessor2" />

<integration:service-activator id="serviceActivator3" input-channel="sharedInput"
                               ref="messageProcessService" method="callMsgProcessor3" output-channel="reqChannel" />
```

among above 3 serviceActivator, the output-channel of the last one is defined as IBM mq in another xml configuration file.

**now my job is to generate a different message from sharedInput, and send to a different queue in parallel**

so I add a line as below

```
<integration:service-activator id="serviceActivator4" input-channel="sharedInput"
                                   ref="messageProcessService" method="callMsgProcessorNew" output-channel="reqChannelNew" />
```

however when running JMS, the message from sharedInput only goes to callMsgProcessor3, and the populated message is sent to reqChannel only as well, and ignore my new destination. if I comment out the third service activator, sharedInput can go to callMsgProcessorNew, and route to new queue.

can anyone advise how I should configure to push the sharedInput go to two processors (callMsgProcessor3 and callMsgProcessorNew), and also sent to their corresponding output mq channel in parallel?

I googled online, seems router splitter or recipient list router can solve my problem? but still feeling confused after reading the related doc, and not sure how to configure it in my case. appreciate if someone can help provide a sample

please let me know if I need to provide more info to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `sharedInput` as a PublishSubscribeChannel and have another service activator subscribed to it so the same message will go to both of them. After that you can make absolutely different flows and do whatever logic you need to parallel. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel.

Also respective EIP determination : https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html

Comment: thank you! I'm able to use recipient list router to solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply, @Artem! I realized one thing, sharedInput only go to one destination is because it is one message. if I can duplicate the message, it will go to two destination. so I add recipient-list-router, and made change as below, and it worked!

```
<integration:recipient-list-router id="duplicateMsgRouter" input-channel="sharedInput"
    timeout="1234"
    ignore-send-failures="true"
    apply-sequence="true">
    <integration:recipient channel="channel1"/>
    <integration:recipient channel="channel2"/>
</integration:recipient-list-router> 

<integration:service-activator id="serviceActivator3" input-channel="channel1"
                               ref="messageProcessService" method="callMsgProcessor3" output-channel="reqChannel" />

<integration:service-activator id="serviceActivator4" input-channel="channel2"
                               ref="messageProcessService" method="callMsgProcessorNew"  output-channel="reqChannelNew" />
```